# How does the Github profile implement this idea?

Tags: github

How does the Github profile implement this idea?

address: https://github.com/poteto

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the source code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/poteto/poteto/master/README.md

GitHub allows you to create a repository with the same name as your username and place a `README.md` file there to be displayed as a "banner" for your profile.

Markdown allows a subset of HTML tags, specifically the `<img>` tag. This `README.md` uses an `<img>` tag to show the animated gif you see when you navigate to this user's profile.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you are really an expert! How did you know this secret?
Why am i so ignorant,
I only recently learned that github has such a feature.